# Qt WebAssembly access to (host) config file

Tags: qt, webassembly

I am planning to convert a QML w/C++ app to WebAssembly, but I am missing a key concept.  This app reads a local config file on startup to load preferences, and also to determine the IP/port of a related service.

If I convert this to WebAssembly, how does the app access the config file?  (Or even find the host with the config file)?  Does part of the app still run on the host and part in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Qt uses an emulated file system, it can be in-memory or based on the Indexed DB (IDBFS). By definition webassembly is sandboxed, and you can not access any file in the host OS, unless provided by the user explicitly.

You can just create the file on startup the first time and update it afterwards, it will work just as a regular file, but it will be stored in the browser Indexed DB, if an user deletes the cache/files of your website the config file will be lost.

You can also request the file to the user using `QFileDialog::getOpenFileContent()`. Se a detailed description at https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly#Files_and_local_file_system_access